# Repeat an If if it this false

Tags: javascript

I want to know if is possible to repeat a If if the If goes to else, let me show you my code.

```
    var image = document.getElementById("image");
var right = document.getElementById("right");
right.addEventListener("click", moveRight);


const vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0)
var imageX = 0;
function moveRight(e) {
   imageX += -vw;
   image.style.position = "relative";
   image.style.transform = "translateX(" + imageX + "px)";
   e.preventDefault();
}

var left = document.getElementById("left");
left.addEventListener("click", moveLeft);

function moveLeft(e) {
    imageX += vw;
    image.style.position = "relative";
    image.style.transform = "translateX(" + imageX + "px)";
    e.preventDefault();
}

function getTranslateX(element) {
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(element)
    const matrix = new DOMMatrixReadOnly(style.transform);
    var value = matrix.m41;
    return {
        value
    }
}

if(imageX > 0) {
    document.getElementById("left").style.visibility = "visible"; 
    console.log('true')
} else {
    document.getElementById("left").style.visibility = "hidden";
    console.log('false')
}

<div class="slideshow">
        <div class="buttons" id="buttons">
        <a id="left"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a id="right"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="image" id="image">
        </div>
    </div>

.slideshow {
    width:13000px;
    height:100%;
}

.image {
    width:12226px;
    background:url(../assets/images/background.jpg) no-repeat;
    height:1080px;
    transition:2s;
}

.buttons {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:30px;
}
```

I want it to repeat the if until the condition is true. I try to use while but It crashes my Google Chrome

That is my code for moment, I am a newbie in Javascript and I am trying to learn everyday more practicing.

Comment: So you want to know when something becomes visible? You should be using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: What's the error message given when chrome crashes?  Are you sure it's the while loop?

Comment: I have a button, when I touch this button the ImageX value increase so when I enter the page I dont want a button to be there I just want to see the button when the imageX value increase

Comment: Chrome do not tell me an error It only close

Comment: You'll need to investigate event handlers that will respond to the size change. How are you changing the `imageX` value (whatever that is).

Comment: I am increasing the value using a function that changes the value of the variable imageX when a button is clicked

Comment: Where is this code in the grand scheme of things? When it is being executed? You need to share the relevant HTML, CSS and more of the JavaScript. If you want it run every time a button is pressed, it should be in the callback of a `click` event handler attached to the button.

Comment: Thanks I will try that

Answer (score -1):

why you don't use any function ???

```
const foo=(imageX)=>{
   if(imageX>0){
      document.getElementById("left").style.visibility = "visible"; 
      console.log('true')
      return true
   }else{
        document.getElementById("left").style.visibility = "hidden";
        console.log('false')
        return false
   }
}



// for example
let imageX = 5



if(foo(imageX)){

  // some code 

  foo(imageX)      

}else{
  // some code
}
```

Comment: in while loop you just use  ==  or  === operator